# Accelerometer Shaken event in windows universal app doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, win-universal-app, shake

I try to detect a shake on my phone with the Shaken event from Accelerometer object. The accelerometer object is not null but when I shake the phone, it never go in the `_accelerometer_Shaken` event.

```
    public int shakeCount = 0;
    Accelerometer _accelerometer = Accelerometer.GetDefault();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        if (_accelerometer != null)
        {
            _accelerometer.Shaken += _accelerometer_Shaken;
        }
    }

    async private void _accelerometer_Shaken(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerShakenEventArgs args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            shakeCount++;
            tbInfo.Text = shakeCount.ToString();
        });

    }
```

I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not supported yet.

This is an extract from the official sample code

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Accelerometer

> **Accelerometer Shake Events**
>
> When you choose the Enable button for the Shake Events option, the app
>   displays the cumulative number of shake events each time an event
>   occurs. (The app first increments the event count and then renders the
>   most recent value.)
>
> Note that shake events are not supported in Windows 10 build 10240, so
>   the Shaken event will never be raised, but the sample demonstrates how
>   to handle the event when support for shake is added.

I made a test under Windows 10 10586 and it still does not work.

Comment: So stupid to implement a method that doesn't work... thanks for the info